# Using awk to sum an integer to a column in bash

Tags: bash, if-statement, awk, sum

I have a file (tmp0.tmp) of one column with negative and positive values, like this:

```
-109.372
-152.846
121.435
122.107
-1.172
-118.116
```

I want to sum 360 to each negative value, and keep the positive ones in the same position.

I did:

```
for file in tmp0.tmp
do
awk '{if ($1 < 0) {print $1+360} elseif {print $1}' $file > histogram.dat
done
```

and it didn't work.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks

Comment: Read the syntax error messages and fix them with the help of the man page and/or google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using `awk` , no need use `loops`

```
awk '$1<0{$1+=360}1' inputfile
250.628
207.154
121.435
122.107
358.828
241.884
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another way with **`bash`** + **`bc`**:

```
while read -r n; do echo "if ($n<0) $n+360 else $n" | bc; done <tmp0.tmp
```

The output:

```
250.628
207.154
121.435
122.107
358.828
241.884
```